# Lightning Dynamic form, with 3 columns Layout

Tags: lightning, lightning-layouts, dynamic-forms

In the preparation of the Admin Salesforce Certification, i had this question:

[image]

The thing is, i know Dynamic forms can be used to dynamically hide fields based on conditions. Not to add a column to the layout. But yet, they do have it here:

[image]

And in the related forum, they all insist it can be done, never showing how to, linking to that info. Also, i cannot find this anywhere. Ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the Lightning page template to 'Header and Three Regions'.  As long as you have the three sets of fields as separate sections in your page layout, you can then drag and drop each section into the relevant column and arrange the fields how you like, using Dynamic Forms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That was it!!